# EXIF like thing for Videos

Tags: c++, python, c, perl, exif

Is there any standard way to get information from a video file? For images we have EXIF data which can be used to get information about the date/time , size etc of the image file. I was wondering if there is such a thing for videos as well.

The use case is - I have lot of videos which I shot from my digital camera. I want to rename them to something more meaningful like YYYY-MM-DD rather than Video_N . The YYYY-MM-DD should be the date and time when the video was shot.

Any solution in Python, C/C++, Perl would be appreciated but if you have solution in other language, please do let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Kind of important to know what format they are in, or at least what extension they have.

Comment: @ysth Thanks for your participation. The format is MPEG but I want to develop a tool which I can send to my friend and he can use it without any modification. His camera might be different.

Answer (score 7):

[exiftool](http://p3rl.org/exiftool) reads video containers and their metadata.

Comment: Note that exif DateTime for still images is specified as local time (But UTC for GPS tags).  I don't know whether there is a standard for videos, but I do know that iPhone complies with the standard for photos but uses UTC for videos (at least as reported by exiftool).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, most cameras don't actually store enough metadata in the video :(.

If they are storing it, due to the wide variety of video codecs and containers like AVI, MOV, MPG, MP4, etc., a good option will to run ffmpeg -i  to read it.