# How to get aspect ratio from video file?

Tags: linux, perl

How to get aspect ratio from video file ? ( 16:9 or 4:3 for example ) ?

Comment: perl-magick ? http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php

Comment: Look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422387/get-aspect-ratio-of-video-from-ffmpeg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248347/exif-like-thing-for-videos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the tool [mediainfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/). Run it with `mediainfo -f --Output=XML <file>` to examine it.

PS: In my case (openSUSE, mediainfo 0.7.34, the option `--Output` was ignored).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ffmpeg` to do that:

```
my ($aspect) = `ffmpeg -i filename.mov 2>&1` =~ /DAR\s*(\d+:\d+)/;
```

Or `ffprobe`:

```
my ($aspect) = `ffprobe -i filename.mov -show_streams 2>&1` 
             =~ /display_aspect_ratio=(.+)/;
```